# Field not separable

Tags: extension-field

Are there fields which are not separable?

I have seen that the field of characteristic 0 and finite fields are all separable or has separable extensions.

Comment: yes, $k(t)$ is an inseparable extension of $k(t^p)$

Comment: Is this for a field of characteristic $p$?

Comment: Inseparable if and only if characteristic $p$

Comment: What do you mean by a field being separable? Do you mean perfect? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field)